# If have old .rvm directory and rebuilding rails from clean El Capitan install, should it be deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had a "contaminated" environment on my El Capitan for rails and could not get brew to work. I cloned my drive, erased hard drive, re-installed El Capitan, then migrated from clone only Apps and User area without and ports or "other files". Moved .bash files out of ~ and then logged out and back in. I have ruby, as I should, and no rails. I have nothing other that bar directory under /use/local, and no /opt/local anymore. However, I do have a .rvm directory left over. Before I start the process of installing brew, rvm, rails, etc. should I delete .rvm directory or will that kill me?

Comment: It stands to reason that if you have a completely clean install and haven't installed RVM, then that `.rvm` directory can be safely nuked since RVM will create a new one when you install it. Of course, having not faced this situation myself, I can't make any guarantees, but I can't find anything online that suggests you'll have a problem.

Comment: before using `rbenv` instead of RVM, i used to remove the `.rvm` directory regularly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the .rvm directory and used rbenv to install plus gem install rails -v 5.0.0 successfully on El Capitan. The problem I had was mixing Fink, Ports, and Brew plus messing up the path with all the various things I was doing. Simplified it and now all is well!
Thanks for reassurance.